# gwt component mapping trouble

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt

I am studying to use gwt in my web-project, but came across one trouble. I create a button:

```
public class Example implements EntryPoint
{
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        Button btnStart = new Button( "Start" );
        RootPanel.get().add( btnStart );
    }
}
```

in my war-module of web-project and deployed it on jboss. After going to `http://localhost:8080/war/` I saw nothing at all except greeting of my Example.html:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Example Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Example.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.tests.gwt.Example.nocache.js"></script>
<h1>Example Application</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look correct:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.tests.gwt.Example.nocache.js"></script>
```

I suspect the module name is missing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="your_modulename/Example.nocache.js"></script>
```

[image: That's how your war should look like]

Answer (score 1):

Your nocache.js is in a the com.tests.gwt.Example directory.

Your script src must be :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.tests.gwt.Example/com.tests.gwt.Example.nocache.js"></script>
```

You can use the rename-to in the gwt.xml module file for simplify the module name :

```
<module rename-to="example">
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <entry-point class="com.tests.gwt.Example" />
</module>
```

The script tag will become :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="example/example.nocache.js"></script>
```